# 404 with simple Express routing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to set up routing in my Node.js app using Express.js and Mongoose.js using this tutorial - [Learn to Build Modern Web Apps with MEAN](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack)

When I test with cURL, it gives me this message:

(the curl script is: `curl --data 'title=test&link=http://test.com' http://localhost:3000/#/posts`)

```
Error: Not Found
    at /Users/adamz/flapper-news3/app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at /Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603:15
    at next (/Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:14)
    at Function.proto.handle (/Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:3)
    at router (/Users/adamz/flapper-news3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.
```

For reference my app.js file is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

And my routes/Index.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});


router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);

  post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Is something out of order? I copied and pasted directly from the tutorial, Node.js is running, mongodb is running, so I'm really not sure what's going on.

Let me know if any other info would help. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you check the node_modules folder and verify that cookie-parser is installed?

Comment: Yes, cookie-parser is installed

Comment: when you start your server, what are you running?  Did you use the express generator to start this project?

Comment: Yep I used the express generator. To start the Node App I just execute 'npm start' in the terminal. I am able to hit the site pages in the browser fine -  so the Angular routing is working just not the Express routing.

Comment: Maybe wrong link in curl? It's http://localhost:3000/posts without #. And if you want to POST with curl use -X flag. curl -XPOST --data 'title=test&link=http://test.com' http://localhost:3000/posts.

Comment: yep...take out the hash

Comment: https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/#opening-rest-routes-testing-the-initial-routes

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't work either. To be clear when i type curl http://localhost:3000/posts I aso get a 404 but if I add the '#' curl http://localhost:3000/#/posts it returns the html for the page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your curl script should include quotations around the site:

curl --data "title=test&link=http://test.com" "http://localhost:3000/posts"

Answer (score 0):

You need to define mongoose before express:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and got stucked with the same error, then I just restarted the node server and it worked just fine.